# Why GeoServer illustrates SVG symbols only partially?

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld, svg

I have few SVG symbols that are names based on an attribute value of the table of attributes of my point ShapeFile layer.

I want to illustrate the corresponding SVG for each point where the field "drapeau" has value that matches the name of the SVG symbol.

I have the following SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>poi</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>poi</Name>
      <Title>Points of interest</Title>
      <Abstract>Manhattan points of interest</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>point-rule</Name>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="file:///C:/GeoServer 2.7.1/data_dir/styles/VN301/${drapeau}.svg"/>
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>20</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Then, I have the following SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   inkscape:version="1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)"
   sodipodi:docname="RRRR.svg"
   id="svg4513"
   version="1.0"
   height="49.741665mm"
   width="41.804165mm">
  <defs
     id="defs4517" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg4513"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:window-y="-9"
     inkscape:window-x="1711"
     inkscape:cy="93.511811"
     inkscape:cx="79.370079"
     inkscape:zoom="2.2463125"
     showgrid="false"
     id="namedview4515"
     inkscape:window-height="1361"
     inkscape:window-width="1720"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     guidetolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     objecttolerance="10"
     borderopacity="1"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     pagecolor="#ffffff" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata4485">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="M 0,3.36 V 188 H 3.6 V 7.04 Z"
     id="path4487"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#4c4c4c" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="M 123.28,0 C 108.96,0 96,6 82.96,12 70,18 56.96,24.08 42.32,24.08 31.6,24.08 20.32,20.72 7.6,12 v 78.319 c 12.72,9.0399 24,12.08 34.72,12.08 14.64,0 27.68,-6.08 40.64,-12.08 13.04,-5.92 26,-11.92 40.32,-11.92 10.72,0 22,3.36 34.72,11.92 V 12 C 145.28,3.3601 134,0 123.28,0 Z"
     id="path4489"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#4c4c4c" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 81.279,50.32 c -28,9.6799 -42,18.4 -69.999,1.68 V 18.4 c 28,16.64 42,7.9999 69.999,-1.68 z"
     id="path4491"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#ffed00" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="M 81.279,50.32 V 50 c -16.64,6 -28.32,11.36 -40.64,11.36 -8.6399,0 -18,-2.64 -29.36,-9.3599 v -33.6 0.32 c 11.36,6.64 20.32,9.3599 29.36,9.3599 12.32,0 24,-5.36 40.64,-11.36 V 50.32 50 50.32 16.72 c -16.64,5.68 -28.32,11.04 -40.64,11.04 -8.6399,0 -18,-2.72 -29.36,-9.3599 h -0.32 v 33.6 h 0.32 c 11.36,7.0399 20.32,9.3599 29.36,9.3599 12.32,0 24,-5.36 40.64,-11.04 z"
     id="path4493"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#1d1d1b" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 81.279,87.679 c -28,9.6799 -42,18.72 -69.999,2 v -33.68 c 28,16.72 42,7.9999 69.999,-1.68 z"
     id="path4495"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#d6151a;fill-opacity:1" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 81.279,87.679 c -16.64,5.68 -28.32,11.04 -40.64,11.04 -8.6399,0 -18,-2.4 -29.36,-9.3599 v 0.32 -33.68 c 11.36,7.0399 20.32,9.3599 29.36,9.3599 12.32,0 24,-5.36 40.64,-11.04 v 33.36 -33.36 -0.32 c -16.64,5.68 -28.32,11.36 -40.64,11.36 -8.6399,0 -18,-2.64 -29.36,-9.3599 l -0.32,-0.32 v 0.32 33.68 h 0.32 c 11.36,6.64 20.32,9.3599 29.36,9.3599 12.32,0 24,-5.36 40.64,-11.04 z"
     id="path4497"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#1d1d1b" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 154.96,48 c -28,-17.28 -42,-8.5599 -69.999,1.04 V 15.36 c 28,-9.6799 42,-18.32 69.999,-0.95999 z"
     id="path4499"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#d6151a" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 154.96,48 0.32,-0.32 c -11.68,-6.9599 -20.96,-9.5999 -30,-9.5999 -12.32,0 -24,5.28 -40.32,10.96 h 0.32 v -33.68 h -0.32 c 16.64,-5.36 28,-10.64 40.32,-10.64 9.0399,0 18,2.64 29.68,9.6799 V 48 l 0.32,-0.32 -0.32,0.32 h 0.32 V 14.4 14 c -11.68,-6.9599 -20.96,-9.6799 -30,-9.6799 -12.32,0 -24,5.36 -40.32,11.04 v 33.68 c 16.64,-5.68 28,-10.64 40.32,-10.64 9.0399,0 18,2.64 29.68,9.5999 h 0.32 z"
     id="path4501"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#1d1d1b" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 154.96,85.359 c -28,-16.96 -42,-8.3199 -69.999,1.28 v -33.6 c 28,-9.6799 42,-18.32 69.999,-1.36 z"
     id="path4503"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#d6151a;fill-opacity:1" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 154.96,85.359 c -11.36,-6.9599 -20.64,-9.9999 -29.68,-9.9999 -12.32,0.4 -24,5.36 -40.32,10.96 v 0.32 h 0.32 v -33.6 h -0.32 c 16.64,-5.68 28,-11.04 40.32,-11.04 9.0399,0 18,2.64 29.68,9.9999 v -0.32 33.68 h 0.32 v -33.68 h -0.32 c -11.36,-7.0399 -20.64,-9.6799 -29.68,-9.6799 -12.32,0 -24,5.36 -40.32,10.72 v 0.32 33.6 c 16.64,-5.6 28,-10.88 40.32,-10.88 9.0399,0 18,2.64 29.68,9.5999 l 0.32,0.32 v -0.32 z"
     id="path4505"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#1d1d1b" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="m 81.279,50.32 c -28,9.6799 -42,18.4 -69.999,1.68 V 18.4 c 28,16.64 42,7.9999 69.999,-1.68 z"
     id="path4507"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#d6151a" />
  <path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\RRRR.png"
     d="M 81.279,50.32 V 50 c -16.64,6 -28.32,11.36 -40.64,11.36 -8.6399,0 -18,-2.64 -29.36,-9.3599 v -33.6 0.32 c 11.36,6.64 20.32,9.3599 29.36,9.3599 12.32,0 24,-5.36 40.64,-11.36 V 50.32 50 50.32 16.72 c -16.64,5.68 -28.32,11.04 -40.64,11.04 -8.6399,0 -18,-2.72 -29.36,-9.3599 h -0.32 v 33.6 h 0.32 c 11.36,7.0399 20.32,9.3599 29.36,9.3599 12.32,0 24,-5.36 40.64,-11.04 z"
     id="path4509"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="fill:#1d1d1b" />
</svg>
```

The SVG files are flag that look like this:

[image]

However, when I use the SLD to create a WMS with Geoserver and then I use Geoserver's OpenLayers to view the WMS, I have this:

[image]

The problem is that only the upper left corner of the SVG is displayed.
What is the problem?

Note: My SVG files does not have a "viewBox" and when I tried to add one, still the WMS was not correct.

What should I do?

As @Turton suggested, I have increases the size in the tag               40 to 40 and I used Version 2.22.0 of Geoserver, but this is the resulting image:

[image]

flags got bigger, but still they are displayed only partially.

The strange this is that there are three flags at the upper right corner that are displayed correctly. This is the SVG of one of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xml:space="preserve"
   enable-background="new 0 0 118.697 114.678"
   viewBox="0 0 119.494 147.65787"
   height="147.65787"
   width="119.494"
   y="0px"
   x="0px"
   sodipodi:docname="TNJR.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)"
   id="svg4513"
   version="1.1"><metadata
     id="metadata12"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs10" /><sodipodi:namedview
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     inkscape:window-height="1361"
     inkscape:window-x="1711"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1720"
     inkscape:window-y="-9"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg4513"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     id="namedview4515"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.2878356"
     inkscape:cx="18.822612"
     inkscape:cy="29.285582" /><path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\TNJR.png"
     style="fill:#4c4c4c;stroke-width:0.9826985"
     d="M 0.198,0 0,147.65787 H 2.719 L 3.312,0.51471615 Z"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc"
     id="path4487" /><path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\TNJR.png"
     style="fill:#4c4c4c"
     d="m 93.081,3.046 c -10.813,0 -18.5,5.408 -28.346,9.234 -9.772,3.843 -20.289,11.377 -32.583,13.204 0,0 -18.282,3.554 -26.215,-15.572 L 5.739,59.597 c 9.604,5.766 18.121,7.704 26.215,7.704 11.053,0 20.899,-7.024 30.684,-10.852 9.846,-3.775 21.216,-11.536 32.028,-11.536 8.094,0 14.63,6.864 24.233,12.323 l 0.595,-44.702 C 109.89,7.024 101.175,3.046 93.081,3.046 Z"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="scsccscsccs"
     id="path4489" /><path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\TNJR.png"
     style="fill:#fff200"
     d="m 61.369,52.582 c -21.141,9.68 -31.712,18.72 -52.852,2 v -33.68 c 21.141,16.72 31.711,8 52.852,-1.68 z"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path4495" /><path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\TNJR.png"
     style="fill:#1d1d1b"
     d="m 61.369,52.582 c -12.564,5.681 -21.383,11.04 -30.685,11.04 -6.524,0 -13.591,-2.399 -22.168,-9.359 v 0.319 -33.68 c 8.578,7.04 15.343,9.36 22.168,9.36 9.301,0 18.121,-5.36 30.685,-11.04 v 33.36 -33.36 -0.32 c -12.564,5.68 -21.383,11.36 -30.685,11.36 -6.524,0 -13.591,-2.641 -22.168,-9.36 l -0.242,-0.32 v 0.32 33.68 h 0.242 c 8.578,6.641 15.343,9.36 22.168,9.36 9.301,0 18.121,-5.36 30.685,-11.04 z"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path4497" /><path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\TNJR.png"
     style="fill:#dc1f28;fill-opacity:1"
     d="M 117.001,50.262 C 95.859,33.302 85.289,41.942 64.148,51.541 v -33.6 c 21.142,-9.68 31.712,-18.32 52.853,-1.36 z"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path4503" /><path
     inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
     inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
     inkscape:export-filename="Z:\VN301_restriction_Postpanamax\0_CoucheDessin_Active\Drapeau_Image\Fichier_Image\PNG_Format\TNJR.png"
     style="fill:#1d1d1b"
     d="m 117.001,50.262 c -8.577,-6.96 -15.584,-10 -22.41,-10 -9.302,0.399 -18.12,5.359 -30.443,10.96 v 0.319 h 0.242 v -33.6 h -0.242 c 12.564,-5.68 21.142,-11.04 30.443,-11.04 6.826,0 13.591,2.64 22.41,10 v -0.32 33.681 h 0.241 v -33.68 h -0.241 c -8.577,-7.04 -15.584,-9.68 -22.41,-9.68 -9.302,0 -18.12,5.36 -30.443,10.72 v 0.32 33.6 c 12.564,-5.6 21.142,-10.88 30.443,-10.88 6.826,0 13.59,2.64 22.41,9.6 l 0.241,0.319 v -0.319 z"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path4505" /></svg>
```

Comment: You need to make the size of the graphic bigger, and upgrade if you are really using 2.7

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.7 version. How can I upgrade a  production GeoServer?
By size do you mean <Size>20</Size>? If yes, I have already increased it to 45 but it did not change anything

Comment: Replace the war with a 2.22.2 war on test and then on production. It's pretty much impossible to tell you what might be wrong with 2.7 which is 10 years old

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The height and width tag of SVG were not correct.

I opened the SVG in web browser. Then, I right clicked and opened the inspection page that is for debugging javascript.
Then, I found the correct size of the SVG file and I replaced it in the SVG file. Then, GeoServer showed them correctly.